# How to make X.org listen to remote connections on port 6000?

Tags: 10.10, networking, xorg, remote

This is on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) 64-bit desktop.

I want to make my X server listen to remote connections from clients in other machines on the local network. I know about `ssh -X` and that is not what I want. I vaguely remember changing something like `TCPListen` from `no` to `yes`, but I don't remember where this change should be applied.

I'm interested in either a GUI method or a CLI one.

PS editing `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` to remove the `-nolisten tcp` option and rebooting does not work.

Comment: **Hint** It is probably worth disabling the firewall (iptables) while you are trying to get things going.

Comment: @user243114 hint returned unused, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Here follows an almost verbatim copy of a self-answer from an [identical question](https://serverfault.com/questions/99147) on serverfault which I'd forgotten about; askubuntu wasn't yet created).

Based on information found in [this page about enabling XDCMP](http://www.peppertop.com/blog/?p=690) and the file /etc/gdm/gdm.schemas, I managed to create a `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file:

```
# /etc/gdm/custom.conf
[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[security]
DisallowTCP=false

[debug]
```

Take care with letter case: it won't work, if you write "disallowTCP=false"...
I also changed the /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc file to:

```
exec /usr/bin/X11/X
```

i.e. I removed the `-nolisten tcp` options to the X executable. I don't know if I needed to. You might want to try avoiding this edit.

If you only change the xserverrc file, X will nevertheless start with "-nolisten TCP".

After that, all that is needed is a restart of the gdm process:

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

You can verify the success as:

```
tzot@tzot-laptop:/etc/X11
$ netstat -an | grep -F 6000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

### Update

After an upgrade to 12.04, I had the same issue. This time, the culprit is the lightdm that the system uses. The file that needs to be updated is `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and the required addition is a `xserver-allow-tcp=true` in the `[SeatDefaults]` section.

And afterwards, I also found [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72812/). :)

### Synopsis

So, in 10.10 this still works: create `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` with contents as specified above and restart `gdm`.

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04, the only thing needed is having a file like 
`/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/100-custom.conf` containing `
[SeatDefaults]
server-allow-tcp=true
`

Comment: @Nitz, note that's `xserver-allow-tcp=true` you are missing the 'x' in your comment. You could delete your existing comment and rewrite it. Although the answer includes that solution now.

Comment: I [commented on your original question on server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/99147/karmic-koala-ubuntu-enable-remote-x-clients-through-tcp#comment1214930_99152) : now Xorg _by default doesn't listen_ TCP. One needs to add `-listen tcp` to enable it, but `gdm3` doesn't seem to offer this possibility.

Comment: Did anybody make any recent `gdm3` to enable TCP? BTW Ī̲ deem this DM a sack of poorly maintained cruft; poor devels’ job includes lost manpage despite [a bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=979532) pending for 1½ years. Indeed, how is `gdm3` better (for an advanced user) than `sddm` or `lightdm`?

Answer (score 9):

This answer is related to Kubuntu 17.04 and 20.04 and I added it, because none of the other answers (related to [`gdm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager) or [`lightdm`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM/)) helped me. In my case [`sddm`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Desktop_Display_Manager) was running. To check this, run for instance

```
ps -eal | grep sddm
```

If it is is running, processes `sddm` and `sddm-helper` are shown. In this case add a configuration file `/etc/sddm.conf` with content

```
[X11]
ServerArguments=-listen tcp
```

for 20.04 or

```
[XDisplay]
ServerArguments=-listen tcp
```

for 17.04. After creation of this file reboot your system (may be a `sddm` restart is sufficient). As a consequence

```
ps ax | grep sddm
```

shows the desired `Xorg` option `-listen tcp` and the X Server is ready for incoming connections (don't forget to add the remote host with `xhost`).

Comment: Note that as of SDDM 0.14.0 (which ships with Kubuntu 17.10 Artful), the `[XDisplay]` section has been renamed `[X11]`. 

This caused much confusion when I was trying to help my coworker until I ran a `man 5 sddm.conf` on our 16.04 and 17.10 machines respectively, and noticed the discrepancy!

Comment: For the record: it’s possible to install `sddm` onto Ubuntu 22.04 and run it as the default display manager.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 18.04 running as lubuntu 18.04 with lightdm 1.26.0, this is what I had to do (only took me a couple weeks to figure it all out). You have to create both `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and `/etc/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf` as follows:

`sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]

xserver-allow-tcp=true
xserver-command=X -listen tcp
```

`sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]

xserver-command=X -core -listen tcp
```

This will cause lightdm to run Xorg with the following command line:

```
Xorg -listen tcp :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -listen tcp vt7  
   -novtswitch
```

This has "`-listen tcp`" twice, but it doesn't hurt anything. If you don't have both files, one of the Xorg options will be "-nolisten tcp" which overrides the other "-listen tcp".
I finally found the clues to this [here](https://lanforge.wordpress.com/2018/03/30/enabling-remote-x-connections/).

Then add: `xhost +` to your `.bashrc`

Restart and check that Xorg is now listening on port 6000:

```
$ netstat -nal | grep 6000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 3):

As of Ubuntu 18.04, I looked at the running processes and figured out the display manager being used is gdm3:

```
$ ps ax|grep dm
 1515 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/gdm3
```

Then I edited `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and added a line:

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```

As mentioned, opening up port 6000 is not secure. However, I'm using this only at home network and the port is further secured by `iptables` to open up only to my primary laptop, it should be ok.

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer?

Comment: Not fundamentally different but in 18.04 the configuration file is "/etc/gdm3/custom.conf" while in the accepted answer is "/etc/gdm/custom.conf"

Answer (score 3):

The following command works without modifying any configuration options or restarting the window manager.

Open a terminal window and run this:

```
socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:6000,fork,bind=172.17.0.1 UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 &
```

It will open TCP port 6000 as a bi-directional channel to the file system-based socket `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` that your window manager listens to.

The `&` at the end means that the command continues running in the background as long as the terminal is open. For some uses, running it only when needed is more secure, but if you need the port to be always open, I recommend [creating a service with systemd](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6).

On my computer, the `172.17.0.1` is the Docker network card. Alternatively, you can use `127.0.0.1` to limit access to local connections or `0.0.0.0` to even allow connections from outside (Firewall recommended).

When using [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/README) for the first time, you need to install it:

```
sudo apt install socat
```

Tested with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This even allows a TCP connection to `Xwayland` that does not support `-listen tcp`.

Answer (score 1):

For Slim change the option `xserver_arguments` in `/etc/slim.conf`. And restart your X session.

Comment: What is Slim? You should add a link in your answer, so that you demonstrate it's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

On Xubuntu 20.04, which uses `lightdm`, it seems to be cleaner now. Just adding `xserver-allow-tcp=true` to the `[Seat:*]` section of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** you should not edit the file `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc`. Instead copy the file into your HOME directory and give it the name `.xserverrc`. Then edit the file in your HOME directory.

**Second:** these files are only used by `startx`. See the man-page. If you start your X server with another tool, you have to configure that tool appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 20 the only way to put Xorg listening in port 6000 is editing the binary "/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session" and change the string "-nolisten" to "-listen".

Let the "/etc/gdm3/custom.conf" with option: "[security] DisallowTCP=true".

Make a copy of "gdm-x-session" to "gdm-x-session.org" for security. If anything goes wrong you can restore the original file.

Make a copy of "gdm-x-session" in "/tmp". You cannot edit the binary directly , it is opened and the OS does not let you save the changes

To edit, run hexedit (install if not already) and change the string "-nolisten" to "-listen". This string is in the address "0xA46E" of the file, once you have executed "hexedit /tmp/gdm-x-session".

Take care of trailing nulls, this is, the new string in HEX is "2D  6C  69 73 74 65  6E 00 00 00"

Pres Ctrl+X to save and exit.

Go to maintenance mode "init 1".

Copy the "/tmp/gdm-x-session" to "/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session".

Reboot the computer and.. voila !!! "netstat -n -a | grep LISTEN" reports ther is Xorg listening in port 6000.

Comment: I don't know if indeed that is the **only** way with ubuntu and gdm, but on xubuntu 20.04 which uses lightdm instead of gdm things remain configurable.