# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS - Xorg remote connection refused on port 6000

Tags: networking, server, xorg, gdm

I'm having this error when I try connect (Windows >> Ubuntu).

`connection refused on port 6000`

I have no idea how to configure Xorg to accept connections on port 6000.

/usr/bin/X

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Execute Xorg.wrap if it exists otherwise execute Xorg directly.
# This allows distros to put the suid wrapper in a separate package.

basedir=/usr/lib/xorg
if [ -x "$basedir"/Xorg.wrap ]; then
        exec "$basedir"/Xorg.wrap "$@" -listen tcp
else
        exec "$basedir"/Xorg "$@" -listen tcp
fi
```

/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/bin/X -listen tcp "$@"
```

/etc/gdm3/custom.conf

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]
ServerArguments=-listen tcp

[xdmcp]
DisallowTCP=false

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

nmap scan

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00023s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
6000/tcp closed X11
```

i also tried use `xhost +` and `xhost 192.168.0.101` but seems not working. :(

UPDATE

i opened port 6000 stopping gdm3 and start Xorg  `Xorg :0 -ac -listen tcp`but now i dont have graphic interface.

i tried all consoles "ctrl+alt+"

Comment: Please describe the configuration in more detail. What is used on Windows (MobaXterm, VcXsrv, Xming, Cygwin/X). How is Windows Defender Firewall configured? Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on WSL2 ?

Comment: VcXsrv on windows, i can display on ubuntu(bare metal) but not the other way around.

Comment: i opened port 6000 stopping gdm3 and start Xorg :0 -ac -listen tcp but now i dont have graphic interface. i tried all consoles ctrl+alt+x

Comment: Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: nope ubuntu desktop. i can display now but i dont have graphic interface on ubuntu(console 1)

Comment: Try to test MobaXterm portable, more features. In Ubuntu(sudo apt install socat): socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:6000,fork,bind=localhost UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 &  https://askubuntu.com/questions/34657/how-to-make-x-org-listen-to-remote-connections-on-port-6000  https://askubuntu.com/questions/41330/let-xorg-listen-on-tcp-but-only-to-localhost

Comment: So, to be clear, what does a `ps -ef | grep Xorg` show?  Before you tried starting it by hand, I mean.