# How to disable -nolisten?

Tags: xorg

I just installed ubuntu 11.10. I want to run an x-app from another system.

I updated `./xinit/xserverrc` and removed the `-nolisten` option. I rebooted.

I can see that X is started with the nolisten option.

I don't have `/etc/gdm` subdir.

Comment: What purpose you need /etc/gdm dir? 11.10 uses LightDM instead of GDM thats way there is not such folder.

Comment: Note: "I want to run an x-app from another system." While I'm all in favor of modifying your nolisten parameter, for 99% of the use cases, simply ssh'ing to the remote host (possibly with the "-X" parameter, and definitely with "xauth" installed on the remote system) is by far the easiest way to fire up a remote X application. ssh even compresses the transaction, so you might see a slight speed boost.

Comment: I recommend using socat, as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1360248/364151. The solution is not specific to a particular window manager or Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 20):

You need to edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add `xserver-allow-tcp=true` to it.  Here's what mine looks like:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
xserver-allow-tcp=true

[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
```

After that, run this:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

If you have problems restarting, just 'ps ax | grep lightdm' and kill all the associated processes, then:

```
sudo start lightdm
```

I haven't researched yet, but I'm sure there are lots of configuration options for lightdm, I'm just not certain that they all work at the moment.  But this one does.  Here's what my X server process looks like now:

```
2981 tty7     Ss+    0:00 /usr/bin/X :1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 vt7 -novtswitch
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Ubuntu 16.04, it seems to be `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/100-custom.conf`

and it wants to contain:

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-allow-tcp=true
```

[note another user felt the file could also be  `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/100-custom.conf`]

Comment: Worked for me on Xubuntu 19.10 with `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/100-custom.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

edit `/usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas`, setting the key `security/DisallowTCP` to `false`