# Start X without nolisten tcp on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I have ubuntu version 14.04 and lightdm version  1.10.6
I am not able to start X with tcp
There have been similar questions on this forum, but they all point to creating config in /etc/gdm 
I dont have /etc/gdm directory at all on my machine

How can I make my X listen on tcp

Comment: see the "UPD" part of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/615139/421483) (don't follow the "this is a duplicate" link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf  and this solves the requirement

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-allow-tcp=true

[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```