# X server started with “-nolisten tcp” in spite of DisallowTCP=false in /etc/gdm/custom.conf

Tags: gnome, xorg, configuration, gdm

I need to configure a X server in Ubuntu 15.04 gnome which should listening for remote connection on port 6000. I configured my gdm as per [askubuntu question: How to make X.org listen to remote connections on port 6000?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34657/how-to-make-x-org-listen-to-remote-connections-on-port-6000)

Modified /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc as

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/X "$@"
```

Set DisallowTCP=false in /etc/gdm/custom.conf

```
[security]
DisallowTCP = false
[xdmcp]
[greeter]
[chooser]
[debug]
```

Restarted gdm

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

Check wether gdm listening on 6000

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 6000
```

but result is empty

`sudo ps lf -C Xorg` command gives

```
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
4     0  1362  1342  20   0 176672 61764 poll_s Ss+  tty7       0:02 /usr/bin/X :0 -background none -noreset -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-XkGfsT/database -seat seat0 -nolisten tcp vt7
```

Comment: OK, you restarted `gdm`. But was the *X server* restarted then?

Comment: I rebooted my system.

Comment: Try `ps lf -C Xorg` and report the result [in the question body](http://askubuntu.com/posts/672180/edit).

Comment: `ps lf -C Xorg` command shows X running with -nolisten tcp. How can i make it to listen tcp ?

Comment: IMHO this means what did you mean, too. In other words, `gdm` is ∷ ∷d up. By the way, **is  `gdm` even active** at all?

Comment: I found a similar case in [redhat bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1226084). Is it a gdm bug ?

Comment: As a quick&dirty fix, you can move /usr/bin/X to /usr/bin/X~ and leave behind an own wrapper removing “-nolisten tcp” from arguments.

Comment: Or just  ∷ ∷ `gdm` off and install `lightdm`.

Answer (score 2):

After modifying `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` content by adding `ServerArguments=-listen tcp`. I got xserver running on port 6000

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false

[xdmcp]
ServerArguments=-listen tcp
```

Comment: I get this too. I made a similar change in /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas as well, rebooted, and no X11 server listening on port 6000 :(  I even see this:
```shell
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script --allow-remote-connections env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=pop gnome-session --session=pop
```
Note the use of --allow-remote-connections

Comment: @Jobin : is `ServerArguments` documented somewhere? In Linux Mint 19 it doesn't seem to have any effect...

Comment: FYI: this doesn’t work for modern `gdm3`.