# Ubuntu 19 Make X11 listen and accept connections on port 6000

Tags: xorg

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10 my remote TCP-XWindows broke, and I need it for work.

I'm working on a really old currently-in-production system which uses old-style X11 TCP connections.  It *cannot use* SSH X-forwarding.  I need to make Ubuntu accept remote TCP connections (from an aging Solaris box).

This is closely related to [How to make X.org listen to remote connections on port 6000?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34657/how-to-make-x-org-listen-to-remote-connections-on-port-6000). However, I have done everything in the answers and the problem remains.

I need to be able to run a remote X-Windows application, e.g.:

```bash
xeyes -display 192.168.1.111:0.0
```

And have it appear on my local workstation.  But what I get is (of course):

```
Error: Can't open display: 192.168.1.111:0.0
```

I have edited `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, to contain:

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false

[xdmcp]
ServerArguments=-listen tcp
```

I am definitely running `gdm`, and not `lightdm`.

I have also edited `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc`, such that it now says:

```bash
exec /usr/bin/X -listen tcp "$@"
```

Although I expect that `gdm` modifies this anyway.

I have issued the command `xhost +remote_server_name` and `xhost +` (in desperation).

I can see X11 listening on port 6001. (x11-1 is 6001 in `/etc/services` ... why is this not x11-0 / 6000?)

```
$ netstat -a | grep x11
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:x11-1           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:x11-1              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

(and rebooted after these changes).

Has some "extra layer" of configuration been added in Ubuntu 19 to prevent X11 running in this manner?

EDIT: It seems like the processes are running OK:

```
 2196 tty2     Ssl+   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --register-session --run-script --allow-remote-connections cinnamon-session-cinnamon
 2198 tty2     Sl+   16:53 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -listen tcp -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

EDIT2: Update for commenters
The old application is passed the display on the command-line, e.g.: `--display 192.168.1.111:0.0`  It then takes it upon itself to open further windows on the remote display.

I have tried `xhost +`, it made no difference.

Comment: 6001 would be screen :1, so try (on Ubuntu 16.04) 
xinit /usr/bin/xterm -- :1 vt3   The later desktops made running X more of a problem getting another screen up (on virtual term 3 (ctrl-alt-F3).

Comment: How do you start the application on the Solaris machine? What is the DISPLAY variable set up to on it?

Comment: Can you *try* running `xhost +`, and retry the remote X application command? This will disable access control to the running X Server, and will indicate if this is the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I could not connect to port 6000, despite all the options you are talking about.

What finally works is this hack:

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/Xorg
```

and add `-listen tcp` to the Xorg command(s):

```
#exec "$basedir"/Xorg.wrap "$@"
 exec "$basedir"/Xorg.wrap "$@" -listen tcp
```

Then save and exit the file and restart the user graphical interface:

```
 sudo service gdm restart
```

and then check that port 6000 is open:

```
 nmap localhost
```

Comment: This seems like a weird place to put it, but it seems to work for me (Ubuntu 22.04, Xorg, minimal changes to either).  I did make the change to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, too.