# How to make X.org listen to remote connections on port 6000 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: xorg, remote-x-session

Does anyone know how to make Xorg listen on port 6000 under Ubuntu 22.04?

22.04 seems to be running gdm3.

I have modified `/etc/gdm3/session.conf` and rebooted with no success:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
$ ps ax | grep dm
1139 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/gdm3
1878 ?        Sl     0:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]
2835 tty2     Ssl+   0:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session --run-script --allow-remote-connections env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu
2837 tty2     Sl+    0:10 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfs 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -novtswitch -verbose 3
4975 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep dm
$ nmap -p6000 127.0.0.1
...
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
6000/tcp closed X11
$ cd /etc/gdm3
$ diff -U 1 custom.conf_org custom.conf
...
@@ -18,2 +18,3 @@
 [security]
+DisallowTCP=false
```

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186002/ubuntu-19-make-x11-listen-and-accept-connections-on-port-6000) has a "hack" for 19.10. It seems to work but feels like just that, a hack.  Is there an official / better way to get X to listen on port 6000?

I am new to this forum and I can't comment in the [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34657/how-to-make-x-org-listen-to-remote-connections-on-port-6000) or the one for [Ubuntu 19.10 which has a "hack"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186002/ubuntu-19-make-x11-listen-and-accept-connections-on-port-6000).

Comment: Is there a reason that tunneling it via ssh wouldn't work for you?

Comment: @thomasrutter  Not sure.  I was hoping to run graphic apps like darktable and freecad as well as shell stuff.  I don't know what an ssh tunnel can accomplish in that regard; I've always viewed ssh as a text cmd line tool.

Comment: @Nmath  the question you referenced is already referred to in my original post; see the link in "original question".  None of those solutions work.  I would have added a comment to that but I can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make X.org listen to remote connections on port 6000?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34657/how-to-make-x-org-listen-to-remote-connections-on-port-6000)

Comment: @nmath  Agree, bad wording on my part.  The point of the question is that the proposed solution in that article is by the author's admission, a hack.  I'm wondering if there is a more proper / better solution.  Most of the high-value solutions for earlier OS versions involved modifying the config for the dm, not the Xorg command.  If someone with more points wants to move my original question into a comment in that question, fine; otherwise the info for what works and doesn't on 22.04 is lost.